# Grub on Centos 5.2 PC shows "Starting up" on VGA display

Tags: grub, centos-5

I have a CentOS 5.2 PC with Grub. Output is redirected to a serial console.

A snippet of my grub.conf:

```
title CentOS (2.6.18-92)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.18-92 ro root=LABEL=/ console=ttyS0,9600
        initrd /boot/initrd-2.6.18-92
```

During boot up, normally the system shows "Uncompressing Linux..." and a few grub.conf lines on the VGA console. Thereafter the output is redirected to the serial console.

However on this system, VGA shows just a "Starting up" line - serial output looks okay and the rest of the system seems fine.

Why is there a difference in the VGA output?